# How to encrypt a base64 encoded value

Tags: php, encryption, base64

Here I am using file upload,here I did `base64` encode image upto

```
$encodeimage =  base64_encode(file_get_contents($filename));
```

//here we got encoded image value** now I got answer,after that I want to encrypt the `base64` encoded value,I am writing below code but I can't get encrypt value?

```
<?php
require_once 'Security.php'; 

 define ("MAX_SIZE","1000");
 $errors=0;
    $image =$_FILES["file"]["name"];//i got filename here
    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $filetype = $_FILES['file']['type'];
      if ($image) 
      {
      $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['file']['name']);
      $extension = getExtension($filename);
      $extension = strtolower($extension);
     if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) 
      {
        $error_msg = ' Unknown Image extension ';
        $errors=1;
      }
     else{
         $size=filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
        if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
        {
         $error_msg = "You have exceeded the size limit";
         $errors=1;
        }

        if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" )
        {
        $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);
        }
        else if($extension=="png")
        {
        $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);
        }
        else 
        {
        $src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
        }

        list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);

        $newwidth=600;
        /*$newheight=($height/$width)*$newwidth;*/
        $newheight=600;
        $tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);

        imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);

        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];

        imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);

        $encodeimage =  base64_encode(file_get_contents($filename));//here we got encodede image value

        $encrypt_image = "data:".$filetype."base64,".$encodeimage;

        $security = new Security();
        /*$string = $_POST['user_string'];*/
        $publicKey = $security->genRandString(32);
        $encryptedData = $security->encrypt($encrypt_image, $publicKey);

        imagedestroy($src);
        imagedestroy($tmp);
        }
        }

        function getExtension($str) {

                 $i = strrpos($str,".");
                 if (!$i) { return ""; } 

                 $l = strlen($str) - $i;
                 $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
                 return $ext;
         }

        $id_proof = array("filename" =>$filename,
                          "base64_encodeimage" =>$encrypt_image,
                          "encryptedData" => $encryptedData,//getting null value here
                          "error_msg" =>$error_msg
                            );
        echo json_encode($id_proof);
?>
```

Security.php

```
<?php
class Security {

    // Private key
    public static $salt = 'Lu70K$i3pu5xf7*I8tNmd@x2oODwwDRr4&xjuyTh';


    // Encrypt a value using AES-256.
    public static function encrypt($plain, $key, $hmacSalt = null) {
        self::_checkKey($key, 'encrypt()');

        if ($hmacSalt === null) {
            $hmacSalt = self::$salt;
        }

        $key = substr(hash('sha256', $key . $hmacSalt), 0, 32); # Generate the encryption and hmac key

        $algorithm = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128; # encryption algorithm
        $mode = MCRYPT_MODE_CBC; # encryption mode

        $ivSize = mcrypt_get_iv_size($algorithm, $mode); # Returns the size of the IV belonging to a specific cipher/mode combination
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($ivSize, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM); # Creates an initialization vector (IV) from a random source
        $ciphertext = $iv . mcrypt_encrypt($algorithm, $key, $plain, $mode, $iv); # Encrypts plaintext with given parameters
        $hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext, $key); # Generate a keyed hash value using the HMAC method
        return $hmac . $ciphertext;
    }

    // Check key
    protected static function _checkKey($key, $method) {
        if (strlen($key) < 32) {
            echo "Invalid public key $key, key must be at least 256 bits (32 bytes) long."; die();
        }
    }

    //Get Random String - Usefull for public key
    public function genRandString($length = 0) {
        $charset = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
        $str = '';
        $count = strlen($charset);
        while ($length-- > 0) {
            $str .= $charset[mt_rand(0, $count-1)];
        }
        return $str;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to JSON encode a whole image and then its encrypted stream also?

Comment: @HankyPanky, you're right, I corrected it, confusing title.

Comment: Yes,i want to encrypt on encoded image value?

Comment: First step: *why?* What's your security model? What's the attack scenario you're trying to defend against using encryption?

Comment: *"but I can't get encrypt value"* is not enough to go on. Can you describe clearly what you get and what you expect to get? Have you enabled error reporting? Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($ivSize, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM); # Creates an initialization vector (IV) from a random source,this line i am getting null value encrypt function

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that you or others cannot decrypt it the reason might be that you in the comment set that you are using AES 256 but in the code you are setting the algorithm to AES 128, did you mean CRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 instead of CRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128?

Also is there a reason why your encrypt function is static when you are not using it in a static way?

Comment: $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($ivSize, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM); # Creates an initialization vector (IV) from a random source,this line i am getting null value encrypt function

Comment: Which OS and php version are you using?

Comment: What do you get if you add var_dump($iv); after creating the $iv? Do you get any errors? I did copy your code and get an IV and encrypted data when testing the code using php 5.6 on Ubuntu

Comment: How to use var_dump() in encript function and also how to return previous page

Comment: Create a test function to test only this part, for instance by running the code you have here in a unit test (or in a function you can call from command line)